# redis how to get first key-value pair of hash map

Tags: redis

I would like to have something like the following table in redis.

| host name | back queue |
| --- | --- |
| stanford.edu | 23 |
| microsoft.com | 17 |

As far as I know, the best way to implement this is to use redis hashes (with host name as key and back queue as value). However, in my use case, I also want to get the first key-value pair present in the hash map.

How can this be implemented? Are there any redis datatypes specifically for this?

Comment: What's your definition of "first"?  Depending on your answer, a Sorted Set might be better.

Comment: but then in a sorted set can I store the hostname and back queue together? Can you please give me an example? thanks!

Comment: Yes - the back queue would become the score in the sorted set.  [The docs](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sorted-sets) have better examples than I can provide here!

Comment: also, I want to make sure that the host name and back queue are unique @JamesThorpe